# how to deploy Maven dependencies automatically into JBoss as OSGI bundles?

Tags: maven, deployment, osgi, jboss7.x, apache-servicemix

I have a project that deploys an standalone OSGí Apache ServiceMix application. It has tons of dependencies and it is built with Maven. Now I want to deploy this application into a JBoss AS. I found an interesting Maven plugin called `jboss-as-maven-plugin` (`org.jboss.as.plugins`) to deploy anything. I use `maven-bundle-plugin` (`org.apache.felix`) to construct my bundles and it works fine, but when I deploy the project bundles, the deployment fails because dependencies are not satisfied.

How can I automatically bundle and deploy all the dependency tree with a Maven goal? Is it possible? My project has dozens of dependencies declared on the `pom.xml` and some of them are other projects in my workspace.

Comment: @Lucas Tycho isn't relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only solution to this I know are the Karaf features. You can [create a feature file out of your pom dependencies](http://icodebythesea.blogspot.de/2012/03/making-osgi-deployments-easier-with.html).

I found that jboss seems to support [subsystems](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/OSGi+subsystem+configuration). That may help to specify the bundles required to run your application. It does not seem to be the OSGi subsystem spec but for jboss this may already help. For OSGi spec 5 there is the standardized subsystem spec which may provide a standard way to do this across containers.

If jboss supports OBR (OSGi bundle repository) then you can limit the number of dependencies you have to specify.

Comment: I have used subsytems of JBoss but I have not achieved my objective using that as it is shown in a JBoss 7.1 issue (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-5544), see my last comment. Karaf  is a dependency itself because I have not achieved to have a well-configured instance inside JBoss. I'm having many problems to achive my objective :-(( . thank you, I keep on trying!

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to simply use Karaf as a server instead of JBoss?

Comment: it is a requirement to deploy our app into JBoss. We must support both, standalone Apache ServiceMix (with Apache Karaf) and JBoss deployment.

Comment: Ok I understand. From a framework developer perspective it is quite bad at the moment that there is no common way to specify groups of bundles that works for all OSGi containers. I hope the subsystem and repository spec will close that gap but it will take some time till these are supported.

Comment: yes, I followed the issue guidelines, but it seems all the feature will be completely deployed in JBoss AS 7.2. we have no time to wait the stable release :-((

Answer (score 0):

If your application do not use OSGi per see, you may consider packing your application as a WAR which is deployable in JBoss.

Then you would need to use web.xml to bootstrap your application, such as using a Spring XML file.

There is a Camel example as a WAR here: http://camel.apache.org/servlet-tomcat-example.html

Comment: obviously our application uses OSGi, that's the reason why we choose Apache ServiceMix (and Apache Felix as OSGi container). our application consists in a set of OSGi bundles and features.

Comment: Yes okay, but you may deploy in OSGi container and NOT use any OSGi services such as the osgi service registry, or its config admin service etc. If not using that, you can deploy your app in non OSGi containers.

Comment: our app uses the service registry. in fact our app uses OSGi services intensively.

Answer (score 0):

You can autoinstall your bundles with org.apache.sling plugin

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-bundle</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <slingUrl>http://localhost:8181/system/console/install</slingUrl>
                    <user>karaf</user>
                    <password>karaf</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

you can find detailed pom.xml from Adobe website :https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/developmenttools/how-to-build-aem-projects-using-apache-maven.html

or http://www.cqblueprints.com/tipsandtricks/build-and-deploy-osgi/build-deploy-osgi-1.html